# PWA (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed) error

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, progressive

this is my code
I don't understand where this error is coming from i have tired methods from provious post but this doesnt seem to work.
pls help 
thanks in advance.

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxpVJ.png)

[this is my service worker code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usNAt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to a failure when calling `cache.addAll` with paths that don't exist on the server the SW is making its requests to. You have to be very careful with the paths.

What would *probably* fix your problem is prepending a slash (`/`) to all your asset paths (eg. `main.js` -> `/main.js`). This is, of course, pure guessing since I don't really know what files are sitting on your server.

If you remove all of them (comment out for example) and add back to the `cacheAssets` array one by one you will see which causes the problem =)

Comment: Thanks i found the problem it was a typo. i cant believe i didnt spot it all this while